# Can't open *.ini files in Xubuntu 19.04

Tags: xubuntu, files, text

I don't know why, but I'm not being able to open `*.ini` text files. Every time I double click on them a working icon appears next to the pointer and then nothing happens.

The last major change I did in the system was installing Wine and Lutris.
I did upgrade to Disco Dingo from Cosmic Cuttlefish a couple of days ago, but I was already having this problem before the update.

This is the result I get in the terminal when I try to open the file acting as super user in Thunar:

```
camilo@camilo-S400CA:~$ sudo thunar
[sudo] password for camilo: 
env: ‘/home/ubuntu/buildbot/runners/wine/tkg-3.20-x86_64/bin/wine’: No such file or directory
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: did you try `right click > open with` option?

Answer (score 1):

You could right-click on an .ini file, select properties then open with and choose Text Editor, Set as default.

Answer (score 0):

Already solved it. It was a problem with wine and notepad (windows text editor).
Somehow, afterinstalling wine or mono, or both, the default text editor for *ini files changed automatically to notepad.
Thanks to everyone who answered

> Blockquote